# Non-english based keyboard & input method

Tags: android

I'm new to android app development so I'm sorry if my questions sound amateur. I've tried to search for an answer to my question online but I think I might not be using the correct lingo because what I am trying to do isn't something new. Please help me get on the right path.

I want to create an app in which one of my pages has available a keyboard in a different language. The language cannot be represented by english letters but there are fonts available for it in windows, etc so it is a known language. I would like the user to select the letters from the keyboard and the letters to be printed into a text box in that same language. Next, using the letters that the user inputted, I would like to do a search through a database for that particular string of letters and find the page number that the inputted line is located on.

Part 1:
I'm trying to figure out which approach I should use in constructing the keyboard. What I have come up with is that I need to create a table of image buttons that has an image of each character on it. Is this a good approach or is there a better way to do this?

Part 2: 
When the user selects the a letter from the table of image buttons, how to print it in the particular language? I did create a strings.xml under res/values-pa (I looked this up and the ISO 639-1 Code is "pa") for this language. What I don't know how to do is get the characters in that language to be printed when the user selects it from the keyboard?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a full featured keyboard, look up the InputMethodService and derive a class from it.  The user can then select it as a keyboard.  But if you just want to have them input text in their native language, all they need to do is select that as their locale and have a keyboard that supports that locale installed on the phone-  it would be very unusual and probably wrong for you to be coding a keyboard.  Not to mention a good keyboard takes a ton of work-  the big Android keyboards have teams of programmers and linguists on them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to need to include a font for that language in your app. There's a good tutorial on including and using them [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/).

After that, You could set the text of each of your buttons to one of the characters from that font.

Then in the onClick() of every button, do something like:

```
String letter = clickedButton.getText();
myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText() + letter);
```

Where `clickedButton` is the button that was clicked and `myEditText` is your EditText